# Manually Handling ARKit Session State Preservation and Restoration After Force Quit

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm working on an iOS app with ARKit, and I need to implement a solution for resuming the ARKit session after the app has been force-quit and relaunched. As ARKit does not inherently support automatic resumption after force quitting, I understand that I need to handle the session state preservation and restoration manually.

1. Enable session state preservation in an ARKit view controller.
2. Implement the necessary ARSessionDelegate methods to handle session list item state changes and interruptions.
3. Save and restore the AR session state during relevant app lifecycle events in the app delegate.
4. Handle data persistence and restoration for any anchors or objects in the AR scene.

Any insights, code snippets, or best practices would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!